# Woocommerce: How to display prices with decimals

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On website the prices must be displayed without decimals, but I need to display decimals in the invoice.

For example, Product1 price displayed on website is $ 15. If I change the general settings to hide decimals it will hide decimals in invoice as well, and I need it to be $ 15.00

Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks,
Nicu.

Comment: I am not sure but you may check for theme-ajax,php, script.js and database connection file with number_format() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a filter hook that you can work with. I am not sure if there is a hook for invoice as well, but you can conditionally turn this hook on depending on the page the user is viewing.

```
//In your functions.php
    <?php if(is_product()){
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', 'wc_hide_trailing_zeros', 10, 1 );
        function wc_hide_trailing_zeros( $trim ) {
            // set to false to show trailing zeros
            return false;
        }
    ?>
```

This code should hide the decimals on product pages and show it on invoices. In order for this code to work, i think you have to turn on decimals on the whole website

Answer (score 3):

Running any number through the function woocommerce_price() will format that number with the number of decimals, thousands separator, currency symbol and currency location chosen in the admin.

Add the function to your code snippet should format the price correctly:

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_including_tax() ): ?>
<span class="price"><?php echo woocommerce_price($price_html); ?></span>
```

Source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/how-to-display-price-including-tax-with-formatting